# php strtotime giving wrong result

Tags: php

This line of PHP used to add `18 months` to the date `27/12/2013` but it doesn't seem to work any more:

```
echo date( "d/m/Y", strtotime( "27/12/2013 +18 month") );exit;
```

It now returns `01/01/1970`

I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: try this : https://eval.in/83396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the strtotime manual page](http://php.net/strtotime):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601
>   (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So, "27/12/2013" will never work in an argument to `strtotime`.  You can use "27-12-2013" or "27.12.2013" or "2013-12-27" or "12/27/2013"... take your pick. I would, as recommended above, stick with ISO 8601 ("2013-12-27").

Answer (score 3):

Since `d/m/Y` is not a standart type ( the standart would be `m/d/Y`, `Y-m-d` or `d.m.Y` ), you need to reformat it and then add the time. I suggest you to use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) for this:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', '27/12/2013' );
$d->modify( '+18 month' );
echo $d->format( 'd/m/Y' );
```

Comment: Indeed the correct answer along the lines of the approach i owuld have taken.

Answer (score 1):

27/12/2013 is not a valid format for PHP. Here are a list of valid formats. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

You'll see, DD/MM/YYYY is not an accepted format.

```
echo date( "d/m/Y", strtotime( "2013-12-27 +18 months") );

Output: 27/06/2015
```

Comment: Edited. It's not that big a deal, geez. Since most other countries do day first, it's typically called American to do month first. If there is another issue with the answer, please explain.

Comment: what does Rasmus Lerdorf's nationality have to do with anything?  In PHP, `strtotime()` doesn't recognize `dd/mm/yyyy` dates.  It does recognize `mm/dd/yyyy` dates.  Ideally, you should probably use ISO 8601 (`yyyy-mm-dd`) dates.

Answer (score 0):

you need to revert the date maybe
    echo date( "d/m/Y", strtotime( "2013/12/27 +18 month") );exit;

Answer (score 0):

Test here: https://eval.in/83396

```
echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime( "+18 months", strtotime("12/27/2013 ")) );
```